# wget: bad address 'github.com'

Tags: docker, dns, dockerfile, wget

I am using the `wget` inside the Dockerfile

```
    FROM wso2/wso2mi:4.0.0
COPY /lib/* $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/lib/
COPY /carFiles/common-20.11.0-SNAPSHOT.car $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/
COPY jdk8.tar.gz $WORKING_DIRECTORY/
#Download and configure Java 8
RUN \
   # wget -O jdk8.tar.gz github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u292-b10/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u292b10.tar.gz; \
    mkdir -p ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/openjdk-8; \
    cd ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/openjdk-8; \
    tar -xf ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/jdk8.tar.gz --strip-components=1; \
    export PATH=${WORKING_DIiRECTORY}/openjdk-8/bin:$PATH; \
    rm ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/jdk8.tar.gz;

ENV JAVA_HOME=${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/openjdk-8 \
    PATH=${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/openjdk-8/bin:$PATH
```

But its failing with the error

> wget: bad address 'github.com' tar: can't open
> '/home/wso2carbon/jdk8.tar.gz': No such file or directory rm: can't
> remove '/home/wso2carbon/jdk8.tar.gz': No such file or directory

i am trying to build the image with this Docker command

```
docker build -f  Dockerfile -t myimage:21.0.82   .
```

then as per the another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64050339/wget-unable-to-resolve-host-address-github-com) post

```
docker build -f  Dockerfile -t myimage:21.0.82  --network host .
```

this also failed with same issue .

If directly i am using

```
wget -O jdk8.tar.gz https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u292-b10/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u292b10.tar.gz;
```

its working fine without any issue . Is this a `Dockerfile` issue or `wget`?

Even this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503454/gitlab-pipeline-docker-build-gets-stuck-on-apk) post not helped .

Comment: Add the entire `Dockerfile` try also to create a new `Dockerfile` with only `FROM ...` and `wget` command. I suspect is a network/proxy related problem.

Comment: @Max Added the full DockerFile Contents ,wget not working when trying from inside DockerFile but when trying outside directly its working in same VM,

Comment: I have started the image `docker run -dt wso2/wso2mi:4.0.0` then I attached to it a shell `docker exec -it containerName sh` and then I submit the command `wget -O jdk8.tar.gz https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u292-b10/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u292b10.tar.gz`. Result: Downloaded without a problem. The issue is in your network.

Comment: `wget` u run from outside of DockerFile or its executing when you executing the Docker build command?

Comment: I don't run the Docker build command I start a container and then I run the commands INSIDE the container, try the same steps and tell me how it went.

Comment: Sorry to say but my requirement is run the wget before making a image file of my application.

Comment: When you run the build command docker span a container (of type FROM clause) and execute commands of Dockerfile. My commands _debug_ your Dockerfile, I suspect that if you try to run the commands above you receive the same error. Otherwise run a container and from the shell try to execute the command in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Look like this issue with all wget from inside DockerFile `wget: bad address 'download.java.net'
The command '/bin/sh -c wget -O jdk8.tar.gz https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk10/ri/openjdk-10+44_linux-x64_bin_ri.tar.gz;' returned a non-zero code: 1
`